# Why do some commands process lines of redirected STDIN data which are already consumed by other commands?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, io-redirection

Supposing we have the following code snippet with a text file `sample.txt` redirected into `STDIN`:

```
@echo off
< "sample.txt" (
    set /P "ONE="
    set /P "TWO="
    findstr /R "^"
)
echo %ONE%, %TWO%
```

...and the content of the related text file `sample.txt`:

```
first
second
third
fourth
```

The output returned on the console is going to be this, which is exactly what I expect (lines `first` and `second` are consumed by `set /P`, hence `findstr` receives and processes the remaining lines):

> ```
> third
> fourth
> first, second
> ```

The same output is achieved when `findstr /R "^"` is replaced by `sort /R`.

However, when replacing the `findstr` command line by `find /V ""` or by `more`, the output will be:

> ```
> first
> second
> third
> fourth
> first, second
> ```

It seems that although `set /P` already consumed the lines `first` and `second` which is proved by the lastly output line, `find` and also `more` still receive the entire redirected data.

Why is this, what causes this behaviour? Is there a way to force `find` or `more` to receive only the remaining redirected data that has not already been processed by a preceding command?

(The behaviour is the same when redirecting the output data `STDOUT` to a text file. Also when executing a command line similar to the above batch code in `cmd` directly, nothing changes.)

Comment: You may read a description of this behavior [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman/28278628#28278628), but the answer to your question is: "because such commands were programmed this way"

Comment: Very interesting, @Aacini! I already suspected that `find` and `more` reset the file pointer, because I played around with all the commands I mentioned, mixed and reordered them, and I even wrapped a `for /F` around them (like: `for /F "delims=" %%L in ('more') do echo(%%L`), which all changed nothing at all. So I fear, there seems to be no (native) way to work around that behaviour?

Comment: You could try to pipe the result of `findstr /R "^"` to `find /V ""` or `more`

Comment: Good idea, @DennisvanGils, piping allows to apply `find` or `more` to be applied on the _remaining_ rather than all data...

Comment: Unfortunately I just found out that the `findstr` method hangs in case the last line of `sample.txt` is not terminated by a line-break; the other commands (`sort`, `find`, `more`) work fine; so there seems to be no reliable way of returning the _remaining_ lines... or do you have any ideas? I tried to pipe a single line-break (`echo(`) into the expression in parentheses, but then the last line gets lost (by `findstr`)...

Comment: You could try `findstr /r "^" > someFile.txt &echo. >> someFile.txt`, then `find < someFile.txt`

Comment: Yes of course, @DennisvanGils, appending a line-break can even be done in advance (with a single `STDOUT` redirection like `> "interim.txt" (findstr /R "^" "sample.txt" & echo()`), it is even possible to replace the `STDIN` redirection by a pipe, like `(findstr /R "^" "sample.txt" & echo()) | (rem /* original code in parens */)`; but pipes I don't like (particularly because of trouble with delayed expansion); the interim/temp. file stuff works, but it introduces additional file I/O operations...

Comment: While not helpful in a technical sense, I think you're finding an interesting holdover from the old `DOS` days.  `FIND`, `MORE`, and `SORT` existed, whereas `FINDSTR` was added later, and may have been written to a newer set of standards.

Comment: @DennisvanGils, your [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423428/why-do-some-commands-process-lines-of-redirected-stdin-data-which-are-already-co#comment62365148_37423428) of piping the data instead does unfortunately not work together with `set /P`, according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351844/piping-into-set-p-fails-due-to-uninitialised-data-pointer)...

Comment: To append a line-break to the last line only when there is none (see also [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423428/why-do-some-commands-process-lines-of-redirected-stdin-data-which-are-already-co#comment62376900_37423428)), `< "sample.txt" find /V "" | findstr /R "^"` could be done because `find` does exactly this job...

Answer (score 1):

> Why do some commands process lines of redirected STDIN data which are already consumed by other commands?

Because some commands/programs rewind stdin.  You can try this:

```
@echo off
< "sample.txt" (
    set /P "ONE="
    set /P "TWO="
    more +2
)
echo %ONE%, %TWO%
```

Result:

```
    third
    fourth
    first, second
```

The `more +2` skips the first two lines of the file.

Comment: By `echo %ONE%, %`, you actually mean `echo %ONE%, %TWO%`, right? This is a nice work-around for the code at hand, but `more` still reprocesses all data (it receives all lines, it just skips two lines from its output)...

Comment: @aschipfl, yes it should have been `%TWO%` not `%`, I missed that.  Just edited the answer.  Yes, `more` still rewinds stdin, in order to process the entire file.  Anyway, I think it's the answer to your question, some programs don't behave like proper filters in a pipe chain.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the spot-on answer to the question as to why commands behave the way they do lies in [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423428/why-do-some-commands-process-lines-of-redirected-stdin-data-which-are-already-co#comment62355738_37423428): »because such commands were programmed this way«.

Anyway, after quite some time, I want to collect my findings and eventually present a new work-around I recently found.

There are only a few commands that seem not to reset the data pointer, and each has got its pros and cons:

1. The usage of `findstr` to return the remainder of the data is already demonstrated in the question. There is the problem that `findstr` may hang when redirected input data is not terminated by a final line-break: [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28278628)
2. `pause` does not reset the data pointer (and this is in fact the reason why I wanted to have it mentioned here), independent on whether the data come from input redirection or from a pipe, **but** it does not provide the consumed character by any means, unfortunately.
3. `set /P` is fine for reading single lines that are not longer than about 1 Kbytes, so for returning the remainder of redirected data you will need some kind of loop:

   ```cmd
    @echo off
    rem // Count total number of available lines in advance:
    for /F %%C in ('^< "sample.txt" find /C /V ""') do set "COUNT=%%C"
    < "sample.txt" (
         set /P "ONE="
         set /P "TWO="
         rem /* Loop here to return the rest; `3` is `1 + 2`, where `2`
         rem    is the hard-coded number of lines already handled; you can
         rem    just use `1` here, which will cause read attempty beyond
         rem    the end of data, causing empty lines to be returned: */
         for /L %%N in (3,1,%COUNT%) do (
             rem // Replace `&&` by `&` to NOT skip empty lines:
             set "LINE=" & set /P "LINE=" && call echo(%%LINE%%
         )
    )
    echo %ONE%, %TWO%
   ```

   Note that `set /P` cannot be used within pipes: [Piping into SET /P fails due to uninitialised data pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41351844)
4. Finally, `sort` can be used to return the remainder. To prevent it from jumbling the lines of text, use the character position option `/+n` and set `n` to a number beyond the actual line lengths:

   ```cmd
    @echo off
    set "ONE="
    set "TWO="
    < "sample.txt" (
        set /P "ONE="
        set /P "TWO="
        rem /* `sort` with the sort position set beyond the lines of text seems to
        rem    simply revert the current sort order; another reversion restores the
        rem    original sort order; I set the sort position just beyond the maximum
        rem    record or line length, which I set to the greatest possible value: */
        sort /+65536 /REC 65535 | sort /+65536 /REC 65535
    )
    echo %ONE%, %TWO%
   ```

   I set the record or line length (`/REC`) to the greatest possible value as it defaults to `4096`. Note that the minimum value is actually `128` in case you specify something less. Also note that line-breaks are regarded for the count as well.