# Piping into SET /P fails due to uninitialised data pointer?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pipe

Supposing we have got a text file `sample.txt`:

> ```
> one
> two
> ...
> ```

Now we want to remove the first line:

> ```
> two
> ...
> ```

A quick way to do that is to use input redirection, `set /P` and `findstr`<sup>1</sup> (I know there are other ways using `more` or `for /F`, but let us forget about them for now):

```
@echo off
< "sample.txt" (
    set /P =""
    findstr "^"
)
```

The output is going to be as expected.

However, why is the output empty when I replace the input redirection `<` by `type` and a pipe `|` :

```
@echo off
type "sample.txt" | (
    set /P =""
    findstr "^"
)
```

When I replace `set /P =""` by `pause > nul`, the output is what I expect -- the input file is output but with the first character of the first line missing (as it is consumed by `pause`). But why does `set /P` seem to consume everything instead of only the first line like it does with the redirection `<` approach? Is that a bug?

To me it looks like `set /P` fails to adequately initialise the reading pointer to the piped data.

I watched that strange behaviour on Windows 7 and on Windows 10.

---

It becomes even more weird: when calling the script containing the pipe multiple times, for instance by a loop like `for /L %I in (1,1,1000) do @pipe.bat`, and the input file contains about fifteen lines or more, sometimes (a few times out of thousand) a fragment of the input file is returned; that fragment is exactly the same each time; it seems that there are always 80 bytes missing at the beginning.

---

<sub>1)  `findstr` hangs in case the last line is not terminated by a line-break, so let us assume such is there.</sub>

Comment: The problem here is the multi-process nature of the pipe. When a file is just redirected there are no problems, but when there are _two simultaneous processes_ at each side of a pipe, one providing data and the other one consuming it via `set /P`, then a problem occur that has been extensively described at [this thread](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6134).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When retrieving data, the `set /p` tries to fill a 1023 character buffer (if they are available) with data from stdin. Once this read operation has ended, the first end of line is searched and once it has been found (or the end of the buffer has been reached), the `SetFilePointer` API is called to reposition the input stream pointer after the end of the read line. This way the next read operation will start to retreive data after the read line.

This works flawlessly when a disk file is associated with the input stream, but as Microsoft states in the [`SetFilePointer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation

> The *hFile* parameter must refer to a file stored on a seeking device;
>   for example, a disk volume. Calling the **SetFilePointer** function with a
>   handle to a non-seeking device such as a pipe or a communications
>   device is not supported, even though the **SetFilePointer** function may
>   not return an error. The behavior of the **SetFilePointer** function in
>   this case is undefined.

What is happening is that, while not generating any error, the call to reposition the read pointer fails when stdin is associated with a pipe, the pointer is not moved back and the 1023 bytes (or the number of available read bytes) keep read.

**edited** in response to Aacini request

The `set` command is processed by the `eSet` function, who calls `SetWork` to determine which type of `set` command will be executed.

As it is a `set /p` the `SetPromptUser` function is called and from this function the `ReadBufFromInput` function is called

```asm
add     esp, 0Ch
lea     eax, [ebp+var_80C]
push    eax             ; int
push    3FFh            ; int
lea     eax, [ebp+Value]
push    eax             ; int
xor     esi, esi
push    0FFFFFFF6h      ; nStdHandle
mov     word ptr [ebp+Value], si
call    edi ; GetStdHandle(x) ; GetStdHandle(x)
push    eax             ; hFile
call    _ReadBufFromInput@16 ; ReadBufFromInput(x,x,x,x)
```

it requests `3FFh` (1023) characters from standard input handle (`0FFFFFFF6h` = `-10` = [`STD_INPUT_HANDLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

`ReadBufFromInput` uses the `GetFileType` API to determine if it should read from the console or from a file

```asm
; Attributes: bp-based frame

; int __stdcall ReadBufFromInput(HANDLE hFile, int, int, int)
_ReadBufFromInput@16 proc near

hFile= dword ptr  8

; FUNCTION CHUNK AT .text:4AD10D3D SIZE 00000006 BYTES

mov     edi, edi
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
push    [ebp+hFile]     ; hFile
call    ds:__imp__GetFileType@4 ; GetFileType(x)
and     eax, 0FFFF7FFFh
cmp     eax, 2
jz      loc_4AD10D3D
```

and, as in this case it is a pipe ([`GetFileType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/aa364960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns `3`) the code jumps to the `ReadBufFromFile` function

```asm
; Attributes: bp-based frame

; int __stdcall ReadBufFromFile(HANDLE hFile, LPWSTR lpWideCharStr, DWORD cchWideChar, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesRead)
_ReadBufFromFile@16 proc near

var_C= dword ptr -0Ch
cchMultiByte= dword ptr -8
NumberOfBytesRead= dword ptr -4
hFile= dword ptr  8
lpWideCharStr= dword ptr  0Ch
cchWideChar= dword ptr  10h
lpNumberOfBytesRead= dword ptr  14h
```

This function will call the `ReadFile` API function to retrive the indicated number of characters

```asm
push    ebx             ; lpOverlapped
push    [ebp+lpNumberOfBytesRead] ; lpNumberOfBytesRead
mov     [ebp+var_C], eax
push    [ebp+cchWideChar] ; nNumberOfBytesToRead
push    edi             ; lpBuffer
push    [ebp+hFile]     ; hFile
call    ds:__imp__ReadFile@20 ; ReadFile(x,x,x,x,x)
```

The returned buffer is iterated in search of an end of line, and once it is found, the pointer in the input stream is moved after the found poisition

```asm
.text:4AD06A15 loc_4AD06A15:                           
.text:4AD06A15                 cmp     [ebp+NumberOfBytesRead], 3
.text:4AD06A19                 jl      short loc_4AD06A2D
.text:4AD06A1B                 mov     al, [esi]
.text:4AD06A1D                 cmp     al, 0Ah
.text:4AD06A1F                 jz      loc_4AD06BCF
.text:4AD06A25
.text:4AD06A25 loc_4AD06A25:                           
.text:4AD06A25                 cmp     al, 0Dh
.text:4AD06A27                 jz      loc_4AD06D14
.text:4AD06A2D
.text:4AD06A2D loc_4AD06A2D:                           
.text:4AD06A2D                 movzx   eax, byte ptr [esi]
.text:4AD06A30                 cmp     byte ptr _DbcsLeadCharTable[eax], bl
.text:4AD06A36                 jnz     loc_4AD12018
.text:4AD06A3C                 dec     [ebp+NumberOfBytesRead]
.text:4AD06A3F                 inc     esi
.text:4AD06A40
.text:4AD06A40 loc_4AD06A40:                           
.text:4AD06A40                 cmp     [ebp+NumberOfBytesRead], ebx
.text:4AD06A43                 jg      short loc_4AD06A15

.text:4AD06BCF loc_4AD06BCF:                          
.text:4AD06BCF                 cmp     byte ptr [esi+1], 0Dh
.text:4AD06BD3                 jnz     loc_4AD06A25
.text:4AD06BD9                 jmp     loc_4AD06D1E

.text:4AD06D14 loc_4AD06D14:                           
.text:4AD06D14                 cmp     byte ptr [esi+1], 0Ah
.text:4AD06D18                 jnz     loc_4AD06A2D
.text:4AD06D1E
.text:4AD06D1E loc_4AD06D1E:                          
.text:4AD06D1E                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
.text:4AD06D21                 mov     [esi+2], bl
.text:4AD06D24                 sub     esi, edi
.text:4AD06D26                 inc     esi
.text:4AD06D27                 inc     esi
.text:4AD06D28                 push    ebx             ; dwMoveMethod
.text:4AD06D29                 push    ebx             ; lpDistanceToMoveHigh
.text:4AD06D2A                 mov     [ebp+cchMultiByte], esi
.text:4AD06D2D                 add     esi, eax
.text:4AD06D2F                 push    esi             ; lDistanceToMove
.text:4AD06D30                 push    [ebp+hFile]     ; hFile
.text:4AD06D33                 call    ds:__imp__SetFilePointer@16 ; SetFilePointer(x,x,x,x)
```

Comment: Very interesting! I initially thought `set /P` initialises the pointer to the piped data wrongly (or not at all); so I put a `pause` command (which perfectly consums the first character as expected) before `set /P` to set the pointer, but `set /P` still failed; this behaviour cannot be explained by my assumption, but by your explanations. Thanks, +1!

Comment: Interesting! +1 I suppose you researched this behavior via a debugger, right? Perhaps you may include in your answer the relevant parts of the listing from the debugger output. **`:)`**

Comment: @Aacini, answer updated. I think I have included the relevant parts, do you find something missing?

Comment: Wow, excellent! Thank you! **`:)`** BTW, did you noted the (do-nothing) `mov  edi, edi` instruction in `; FUNCTION CHUNK AT .text:4AD10D3D`?

Comment: @Aacini, [`mov edi, edi`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110921-00/?p=9583). In this case it was not used. All the tests to locate the `set /p` functionality were done with the debugger attached to the spawned `cmd` instance that was handling the right part of the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

The short summarize of a long discussion at dostips (mentioned already by Aacini 
[set /p problems with pipes](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6134)).

Reading with `set /p` from a redirect, reads always to the end of the line and removes the `\r\n` characters.

Reading with `set /p` from a pipe, reads up to 1023 bytes from the pipe buffer.
It doesn't stop at any `\r` or `\n` characters but it drops all content after a `\n`.
After closing the pipe on the left side, a `set /p` on the right side will read empty lines.