# Batch - why does set /P behave differently with | and with <

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When reading stdin with set /P, it seems that when reading from a pipe it does not work, while reading from a redirection it works okay. This is shown with the following lines:

```
D:\>echo 1 >f1

D:\>echo 2 >>f1

D:\>type f1
1
2

D:\>type f1 | (set line1=&set line2=&set /P line1=&set /P line2=&set line)
line1=1
line2=

D:\>(set line1=&set line2=&set /P line1=&set /P line2=&set line)<f1
line1=1
line2=2

D:\>
```

Why is line2 read in one case and not in the other?

Comment: The difference in those scenarios is that in the first case the whole file contents is passed to the pipe and after finishing the first `set /p` the remainder of the stream is discarded. In the 2nd case only the first line is associated without discarding further input. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts) to better uderstand inner workings of cmd line/batch parser

Comment: Different question but [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41360593/2861476).

Comment: Yes @MCND [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41360593/2861476) is indeed convincing and explains well the different behaviour using the pipe. Knowing this, the next question will be how to read the output of a pipe in a batch file?

Comment: It depends on the specific case, source of the pipe, size of the data, .... The simplest way *could be* to use a `for /f` processing the output of a command reading the pipe, something like `dir /b | for /f "delims=" %%a in ('find /v ""') do @( echo I see: %%a )`

Comment: Indeed @MCND, but it doesn't allow to process the output of the pipe asynchronously. In your example, you will see "I see" appearing only after the dir command has completed. I was using pipes hoping to start the processing by the batch file as soon as the piped command had started producing its output

Comment: Then, in that scenario, the better approach in pure batch is to redirect the pipe into a temporary file while iterating in parallel over the temp file, reading with a input redirected `set /p` to avoid the problems exposed in the previous referenced answer.

Comment: You can find a pure batch approach [here](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5386). An hybrid approach can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10719322/2861476)

Comment: Thanks @MCND, it really helped, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Originally posted by use [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd%20MC) in comments.

posting the same answer as is so this question is not counted in unanswered, question author also confirms in comments that the answer by [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd%20MC) was correct and it helped.

I think enough background, here is the comment as the answer.

> You can find a pure batch approach [here](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5386). A hybrid approach can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10719322/2861476) – [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd%20MC) Apr 2 at 22:03