# Why does set /p only get 1 line from a pipe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipe, stdout, stdin

I was trying to do something like

```
type test.txt | multiline.bat
```

with

test.txt

```
1
2
3
```

multiline.bat

```
set /p a=a
set /p "b=b"
set /p c=c

(echo %a% %b% %c%)>result.txt
pause
```

But result.txt was left with

```
1
```

when I expected

```
1 2 3
```

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/6980605, which said

```
set /p doesn't work with pipes, it takes one (randomly) line from the input.
```

But why??

Comment: You can see "why" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41360593/2861476)

Answer (score 0):

`set /p` stops reading input when it processes a newline. This can be seen with the simple script

```
@echo off
set /p "line=String containing newline:"
echo %line%
```

and then pasting the string

```
one
two
```

Only `one` will be displayed.

---

If you know how many lines you need to process, you can group your `set /p` commands together in a code block and redirect the file to it like this:

```
(
    set /p "a="
    set /p "b="
    set /p "c="
)<test.txt
(echo %a% %b% %c%)>result.txt
```

You could also take the name of the input file as a parameter and change `test.txt` to `%1` in that snippet.

Comment: I know multiple set/p works with the < operator. But why not the pipe?

Comment: @loadingnow, I'd say poor design or implementation, it seems the data pointer seems not to be set correctly...